# Input text does not go to next line when it reaches the end

Tags: html, css

Basically, no matter what I try, the text of my input box keeps continuing in the same line. On top of `word-wrap: break-word;`, I also used `overflow-wrap: break-word;`. I included a code snippet so you can see the problem.
I looked at previous questions on this issue, but none of them work, so I made a new one.

```css
.input {
    min-height: 30px;
    height: fit-content;
    width: 100px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Vowel Counter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vowelcounter.css">
</head>
<div>
<body>
    <h1>Vowel Counter</h1>
    <input class="input" placeholder="Enter your text">
</body>
</div>
<script src="vowelcounter.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: You need textarea, not input element, then you don't even need any css for breaking words

Comment: `input` elements always displays data in single line. Text can't go in multiple lines. Use `textarea` instead or a `div` with `contenteditable="true"` as attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `textarea` not `input` element.

Do it like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Vowel Counter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vowelcounter.css">
</head>
<div>
<body>
    <h1>Vowel Counter</h1>
    <textarea class="input" placeholder="Enter your text"></textarea>
</body>
</div>
<script src="vowelcounter.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. At the time of writing, the only HTML form element that's designed to be multi-line is `<textarea></textarea>`